# Select a list in MemberQ

Tags: list-manipulation

I have bounch of code like:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
face = {6, 8, 7};
pos = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, 10];
vars1 = Flatten[{pos, pts}, {2}];
g=Select[vars1, MemberQ[#, 6, 3] &]
```

`g` results element 6 of the `vars1` which is correct.  How can I replace all the face elements instead of 6 in `g`?

I tried

```
Select[vars1, Table[MemberQ[#, n, 3], {n, {6, 7, 8}}] &]
```

but that does not work!! Any suggestion?

Comment: Is this what you want 
`Table[Select[vars1, MemberQ[#, n, 3] &], {n, {6, 7, 8}}]`

Comment: or maybe `g = Select[vars1, MemberQ[#, Alternatives @@ face, 3] &]`?

Comment: @Hubble07, yes the result is what I was looking for, Thank you.

Comment: @TomD, Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many different way to select the element you want.

(I am not sure if the indices for `x` and `y` are always going to be the same for each `pos` so in the following I am assuming they are not.)

The issue here is to find elements in a list that match a specific pattern.

```
{{x[<element of face>], y[<element of face>]}, <anything>}
```

Usually there are two ways to address the problem.

## Predicate

One possibility is to transform the pattern into a predicate and use `Select`.
A good candidate for the job can usually be found among the `*Q` functions and you correctly identified the right function in `MemberQ` (you want to test whether a whole list matches), but the key to solve your problem is the fact that the second argument of `MemberQ` can be itself a pattern.

```
Select[vars1, MemberQ[#, Alternatives @@ face, 3] &]

(*
==> {{{x[6], y[6]}, {0.903904, 0.851384}}, 
    {{x[7], y[7]}, {0.00501648, 0.268056}}, 
    {{x[8], y[8]}, {0.735388, 0.772411}}}
*)
```

Here I am applying (`@@`) the function `Alternative` on `face` to produce the pattern equivalent of an OR predicate.

Using `MemberQ` this way, however, is not very safe. First, you are testing in *all* the levels up to the third one; to limit your search to level three only you should use the syntax `MemberQ[list, pattern, {3}]`. Second, while in your specific example the coordinated in `pts` are real, in a more general case you don't want to test the whole level three, just the position indices.

The latter issue can be addressed by extracting the part of the expression you want to test *before* using `MemberQ`.

```
Select[vars1, MemberQ[#[[1, {1, 2}, 1]], Alternatives @@ face] &]
```

## Pattern

You can convert the *pseudo*pattern I wrote above in something understandable by Mathematica and use it directly in a pattern matching function, `Cases`.

```
Cases[vars1, {{x[Alternatives @@ face], y[Alternatives @@ face]}, _}]

(*
==> {{{x[6], y[6]}, {0.903904, 0.851384}}, 
    {{x[7], y[7]}, {0.00501648, 0.268056}}, 
    {{x[8], y[8]}, {0.735388, 0.772411}}}
*)
```

## Final remarks

The results of the three methods are equivalent

```
Select[vars1, MemberQ[#, Alternatives @@ face, 3] &] == 
 Select[vars1, MemberQ[#[[1, {1, 2}, 1]], Alternatives @@ face] &] == 
 Cases[vars1, {{x[Alternatives @@ face], y[Alternatives @@ face]}, _}]

(*
==> True
*)
```

Their timing is not (here `n=10^5`)

```
Select[vars1, MemberQ[#, Alternatives @@ face, 3] &] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Select[vars1, MemberQ[#[[1, {1, 2}, 1]], Alternatives @@ face] &] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Cases[vars1, {{x[Alternatives @@ face], y[Alternatives @@ face]}, _}] // AbsoluteTiming // First

(*
==> 0.310922
==> 0.249821
==> 0.013562
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete and useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

For larger numbers of face selections this method is fast:

```
Clear[test]
Scan[(test[#] = True) &, face]
Select[vars1, Or[test[#[[1, 1, 1]]], test[#[[1, 2, 1]]]] &]
```

(Since the OP's `MemberQ[#, 6, 3]` would match `{{x[5],y[6]},{...}}` I have used `Or`.)

Setting n = 10,000 and with 2,000 faces.

```
n = 10000;
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
face = RandomInteger[n, 2000];
pos = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, n];
vars1 = Flatten[{pos, pts}, {2}];
```

*Timing comparisons with Batracos' solutions*

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[
  a = Select[vars1, MemberQ[#, Alternatives @@ face, 3] &]]]
```

> 2.91358

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[
  b = Select[vars1, MemberQ[#[[1, {1, 2}, 1]], Alternatives @@ face] &]]]
```

> 1.59076

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[
  c = Cases[vars1, {{x[Alternatives @@ face], y[Alternatives @@ face]}, _}]]]
```

> 0.23537

```
Clear[test]
Scan[(test[#] = True) &, face]
First[AbsoluteTiming[
  d = Select[vars1, Or[test[#[[1, 1, 1]]], test[#[[1, 2, 1]]]] &]]]
```

> 0.0293339

```
a == b == c == d
```

> True

Comment: Even faster

`ClearAll[test2]`
`SetAttributes[test2, Listable]`
`Scan[(test2[#] = True) &, face]`
`test2[_] := False`

`Pick[vars1, 
 Thread[Or[test2[vars1[[All, 1, 1, 1]]], 
   test2[vars1[[All, 1, 2, 1]]]]]]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something, but, if `pos` and `vars1` are built in this way (with indices in pos sequential), I really do not see the need for using `Select` or similar construct. I think a simple `Part` is enough. Given:

```
n = 10
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
face = {6, 8, 7};
pos = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, 10];
vars1 = Flatten[{pos, pts}, {2}];
g = Select[vars1, MemberQ[#, 6, 3] &]
```

Now (note the order of returned elements):

```
vars1[[face]]
```

> ```
> {{{x[6], y[6]}, {0.678231, 0.683807}}, {{x[8], y[8]}, {0.940556, 0.385775}}, {{x[7], y[7]}, {0.602708, 0.55405}}}
> ```

You can add a `Union` to return in order and avoid duplicates:

```
vars1[[Union@face]]
```

If in your real case index are not sequential (but unique) this trick may works:

```
vars1[[Union@Flatten@Nearest[pos[[All, 1, 1]] -> Automatic, face]]]
```

---

To compare result and performance, on my machine, with other methods, for example the one of @Chris:

```
n = 10000; 
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}]; 
face = RandomInteger[n, 2000]; pos = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, n]; 
vars1 = Flatten[{pos, pts}, {2}];

Clear[test]
Scan[(test[#] = True) &, face]
First[AbsoluteTiming[
  d = Select[vars1, Or[test[#[[1, 1, 1]]], test[#[[1, 2, 1]]]] &]]]
```

> 0.0375143

The one based on `Part`:

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[e = vars1[[Union@face]]]]
```

> 0.000656481

```
d == e
```

> True

If indices are not ordered:

```
pos = RandomSample@Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, n];
Flatten[{pos, pts}, {2}];
```

The method of @Chris:

```
Clear[test]
Scan[(test[#] = True) &, face]
First[AbsoluteTiming[
  d = Select[vars1, Or[test[#[[1, 1, 1]]], test[#[[1, 2, 1]]]] &]]]
```

> 0.0536636

and my method based on `Nearest` gives still good performaces:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  f = vars1[[Union@
      Flatten@Nearest[pos[[All, 1, 1]] -> Automatic, face]]]]
```

> 0.00507884

and its equivalent:

```
f == d
```

> True

Comment: @unlikley, Thank you very much, your code helps a lot as I am supposed to use it for the large number.